# Using Maclaurin series of $\arctan(x)$ to solve the following

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

How would one go about finding the limit of $S_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity, by using the Maclaurin series of $\arctan(x)$?
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$
Thanks!

Comment: See [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.